# Create higher order function for composing and using useReducer into another components gives me an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, composition, higher-order-functions, use-reducer

I want to create a higher order function which contains useReducer hook as a singleton in order to composite with other components.
But i got an error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

My HOF:

```
const initialState = {
  status: ''
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'SHOW':
      return {
        ...state
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const WithReducer = WrappedComponent => (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <>
      <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default WithReducer;
```

And a try to compose:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WithReducer(App));
```

Where did i go wrong ?

Comment: May I ask you why you a trying to wrap a component into an HOC rather than directly using the `useReducer` hook inside the component that needs it?

Comment: The main idea was that we can connect to redux state through connect function without a need to drill props, and i was thinking about repeating that functionality by creating a HOF with a useReducer HOC and connect different parts of my app through a composition. But my mistake was that useReducer creates a new instance of a state and by composing components with my custom HOF i won't have a singleton state but rather independent instances. I thin i should use towards context and useReducer).

Answer (score 2):

got an answer to myself

```
 const WithReducer = WrappedComponent => {
      const Reducer = (props) => {
        const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
        return (
          <>
            <div>{state.status}</div>
            <WrappedComponent {...props} state={state} dispatch={dispatch}/>
          </>
        )
      }
      return Reducer;
    }
```